# Shell script to log output of console

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want to grep the output of my script - which itself contains call to different binaries...

Since the script has multiple binaries within I can't simply put exec and dump the output in file (it does not copy output from the binaries)...

And to let you know, I am monitoring the script output to determine if the system has got stuck!

Comment: The binaries that the script calls will write their output to the same stream that the script does.  If you filter the output of the script through grep, the output of the subsidiary programs will also be filtered.  So what is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you append instead?

```
mybin1 | grep '...' >> mylog.txt
mybin2 | grep '...' >> mylog.txt
mybin3 | grep '...' >> mylog.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this not work?

```
#!/bin/bash

exec 11>&1 12>&2 > >(exec tee /var/log/somewhere) 2>&1  ## Or add -a option to tee to append.

# call your binaries here

exec >&- 2>&- >&11 2>&12 11>&- 12>&-
```